# ionic 4 - how to change a button text programatically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've created a login form with a submit button:

```
<ion-button type="submit" expand="full" color="primary">Log In</ion-button>
```

So, I want to change this button text during form loading.

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {

  ///// HERE CHANGE BUTTON TEXTO TO "PLEASE WAIT"

  this.authService.login(f.value.usuario, f.value.senha).subscribe(
    data => {

      this.authService.loadInitialData().then(value => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
      });

    },
    error => {
      console.log('auth error');
      this.auth_error = true;
    },
    () => {

        ///// HERE CHANGE BUTTON TEXTO BACK TO "LOG IN"

    }
  );
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interpolation

Change...

```
<ion-button type="submit" expand="full" color="primary">{{text}}</ion-button>
```

Now define property inside your class

```
export class HomePage {
...
public text= "Log In";
...
}
```

Now you can change through interpolation, so your code will be:

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {

 this.text= "Please Wait";

  this.authService.login(f.value.usuario, f.value.senha).subscribe(
    data => {

      this.authService.loadInitialData().then(value => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
      });

    },
    error => {
      console.log('auth error');
      this.auth_error = true;
    },
    () => {

         this.text= "Login In";

    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      backButtonText: 'your text here',
    }),
   ...
  ],
```